# Feeding multi-line string value to jquery methods

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, string

How do I feed string variable holding multiline value in it to jquery method like prepend? I need it to construct a form pass by drupal search module like - `$('#divsearch').prepend('<?php print $search_box; ?>').` Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Am I the only one not understanding the final goal here? What's wrong with just passing a string to `prepend`?

Comment: @Nikita - line breaks in the output will throw syntax errors.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode the string, like this:

```
$('#divsearch').prepend('<?php print json_encode($search_box); ?>');
```

This will encode newlines as `\n` instead of literally rendering them...giving you your current syntax errors.

Comment: +1 better than mine, no wonder you're #1 on the weekly rankings :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you can have carriage returns or new lines in you string lets take out the php and show what i mean

```
$('#divsearch').prepend('<div />');
```

this would work

```
$('#divsearch').prepend('<div>some text that goes 
      in a div</div>');
```

this does not work

```
$('#divsearch').prepend('<div>some text that goes'+
      'in a div</div>');
```

this woould